# Is it possible to suppress plotting zero values from datafile column?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, zero

I wrote same data collecting procedure, and over time I added more columns to the data output.
To build a consistent format, the procedure outputs `0` where no measurements were available.

I wonder when plotting the data file whether it is possible *not to plot* zero values (like if no data were present).
Some of the new columns are plotted by themselves (`using 2:7`) and others are used in an expression (`using 2:($7+$8)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option: `set datafile missing "0"`. Note, that a value of `0.0` will be plotted.
This will also plot the lines connected in case you use `with lines` or `with linespoints`

**Code:**

```
### do not plot values "0"
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  1.1
2  0
3  5.1
4  2.1
5  0
6  0.0
7  5.1
EOD

set datafile missing "0"

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7, \
     '' u 1:($1+$2) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image: Example Output]

Also check `help set datafile`, `help set datafile missing` or `help missing`.

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot will not plot values if they are *not-a-number*, i.e. `NaN`. You can either use this string in the data instead of 0, or write a function to convert 0 to `NaN` and use that, eg:

```
chk(x) = (x==0?NaN:x)
plot "file" using 2:(chk($7)+chk($8)) with lines
```

Adding a value to `NaN` results in `NaN`.

Comment: After reading this answer I realized that actually some values had `nan` instead of `0` (program error). The program uses s`sprintf('%12.6g', ...)`. Fortunately it seems `NaN == nan` for Gnuplot. Also the docs say string values are considered to be *invalid*, not *missing* samples.

Comment: @U.Windl Try setting `set datafile missing NaN`